# Interpolate environmental variable into a string

Tags: apache-2.4, variables

In a `<VirtualHost>` block I have this:

```
# Extract the first subdir and assign it to "subdir"
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/?([^/]*)(?:/|$)" subdir=$1

# Add the subdir to the logging path
CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -l c:/logs/%Y.%m_apache_%{ENV:subdir}_access.log 86400" combined
```

But it's not creating the desired:

```
c:\logs\apache_app1_access.log
c:\logs\apache_app2_access.log
c:\logs\apache_app3_access.log
```

I see this error in the error log:

```
AH00106: piped log program 'bin/rotatelogs.exe -l c:/logs/%Y.%m_apache_%{ENV:subdir}_access.log 86400' failed unexpectedly
Invalid filename given
```

Removing this section allows it to work:

```
_%{ENV:subdir}
```

Changing `_%{ENV:subdir}` into `_${ENV:subdir}` fails as well.

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: @AlexD Added to question. Apparently the interpolation is failing.

Comment: @AlexD Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong with the string interpolation?

Comment: I think that `%{ENV:variable}` format is valid for `mod_rewrite`  rules only.